# google app-script weird CORS error because of long request

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

so i make app using simple vanilla html and js which is using api call to web app from google app script last march, and its been working fine, yesterday something weird happen, my app stop working and from console i found out that it give CORS error.
but when i start investigating, i think its because of the waiting time, so the case is like this

my app calling api(g app script) via fetch(GET) ->
api call a function(which is taking roughly 10s) ->
return function output to app

and it causing CORS error, when i try opening the API url directly on new tab, it is working fine, so off course its not function/google script problem

but when i change the google script routine to omit the function, which is like this:

my app calling api(g app script) via fetch(GET) ->
api just return some text to app(which is no loading time)

its working fine now on my app

so my conclusion is, when google app script execute some function that take long time(in my case 10s) it return CORS error when i fetch it, is it right? or im missing something?

here is my gas code:

```
function doGet(e){
      var outp =somefunction();
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'status': outp}))   
  }
}
```

when i change into this, the fetch working fine without cors error:

```
function doGet(e){
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'status': 'sometext'}))   
  }
}
```

edited:
heres the complete code of my google app script(sorry for the spaghetti code)

```
function ambilberkas(prodi,nim,tanggal,tanggalujian,waktu) {
  var templateId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  var folderId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  var container=["nama","judul","waktu","ruangan","ketua penguji","penguji utama","pembimbing","sekretaris","tertanggal","nim","nip1","pangkat1","nip2","pangkat2","nip3","pangkat3","nip4","pangkat4","prodi","telp","tanggalujian"]
  
  var inp=[];
  var target=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName(prodi)
  var lastrow = target.getLastRow();
  var checkData = target.getRange('B2:B' + lastrow).getValues();
  var checkDataFlat = checkData.map(function(row) {return row[0];}); 
  var cekbaris = checkDataFlat.indexOf(nim)+2;
  inp.push(target.getRange('C' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('D' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(waktu);
  inp.push(target.getRange('L' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('F' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('G' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('H' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('I' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(tanggal);
  inp.push(nim);
  inp.push(target.getRange('N' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('R' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('O' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('S' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('P' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('T' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('Q' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(target.getRange('U' + cekbaris).getValue());
  inp.push(prodi);

  var target2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName("DATA PENDAFTARAN")
  var lastrow2 = target2.getLastRow();
  var checkData2 = target2.getRange('B2:B' + lastrow).getValues();
  var checkDataFlat2 = checkData2.map(function(row) {return row[0];}); 
  var cekbaris2 = checkDataFlat2.indexOf(nim)+2;
  inp.push(target2.getRange('H' + cekbaris2).getValue());
  inp.push(tanggalujian);
  
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFilesByName('[' + inp[0] + '] ' + inp[2]);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    files.next().setTrashed(true);
  }
  
  var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId).makeCopy('[' + inp[0] + '] ' + inp[2],DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId)).getId();
  var op = DocumentApp.openById(documentId)
  var body = op.getBody();
    
  for(var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    body.replaceText('{{' + container[i] +'}}', inp[i])
  }
  
  op.saveAndClose();
  
  docblob = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getAs('application/pdf');
  /* Add the PDF extension */
  docblob.setName('[' + inp[0] + '] ' + inp[2] + ".pdf");
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(docblob);
  file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
  return file.getId();
}

function cekstatus(prodi,nim){
  var returndata=[];
    var target=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").getSheetByName(prodi)
    var lastrow = target.getLastRow();
    var checkData = target.getRange('B2:B' + lastrow).getValues();
    var checkDataFlat = checkData.map(function(row) {return row[0];}); 
    var cekbaris = checkDataFlat.indexOf(nim)+2;
    if (checkDataFlat.indexOf(nim) == -1) {
      var target2=SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxx").getSheetByName("DATA PENDAFTARAN")
      var lastrow2 = target2.getLastRow();
      var checkData2 = target2.getRange('B2:B' + lastrow2).getValues();
      var checkDataFlat2 = checkData2.map(function(row) {return row[0];}); 
      if (checkDataFlat2.indexOf(nim) == -1) {
        returndata.push(0);
        returndata.push("Data NIM Tidak Ditemukan, Silahkan Mendaftar");
      } else{
        returndata.push(1);
        returndata.push("Data Sedang Dalam Proses Validasi oleh Staff Akademik");
      }
    } else{
      if(target.getRange('K' + cekbaris).getValue() == "" || target.getRange('J' + cekbaris).getValue() == "" || target.getRange('L' + cekbaris).getValue() == ""){
        returndata.push(2);
        returndata.push("Data Sedang Dalam Proses Validasi oleh Kaprodi");
      } else{
        returndata.push(3);
        returndata.push(target.getRange('F' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('G' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('H' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('I' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('J' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('K' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('L' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('C' + cekbaris).getValue());
        returndata.push(target.getRange('D' + cekbaris).getValue());
      }
    }
  return returndata;
}

function doGet(e){
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined'){
    if(e.parameter.mode == "cekstatus"){
      var hasil=cekstatus(e.parameter.prodi,e.parameter.nim); 
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'status': hasil}))
      setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
    else if(e.parameter.mode == "ambilberkas"){
      var hasil = ambilberkas(e.parameter.prodi,e.parameter.nim,e.parameter.tanggal,e.parameter.tanggalujian,e.parameter.waktu);
      return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({'download disini': 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + hasil}))
      //return ContentService.createTextOutput('{"status":"1XydIGw3Nin8O_aoTBLCs3Ei-AENnRhLU"}')
      setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }    
  }
}
```

and here is my fecth code on the webapp:

```
return fetch('first request to the api URL(another function)')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
            Swal.insertQueueStep({
                preConfirm: () => {
                    * return fetch('second request to the api URL(ambilberkas)')
                        .then(data => {
                            //do something
                        })
                }
            })
        })
```

Comment: sorry its a typo on the closing bracket ( } )

Comment: CORS means you're trying to access a cross origin resource in a browser, and the server does not allow access to the resource - the  request will still take place, the response is still sent, just your code has no access to the response - that's how CORS works

Comment: im sorry, but i think you misunderstood my question, i know what CORS is, but my question is: why two same code from google app script(with the difference only in loading time) resulting two different thing? one with CORS error and other is fine

Comment: and to add more detail, my app working fine from march 2020 to yesterday, which start giving CORS error, i didnt change anything, so i think its maybe on google's part

Comment: In your script, when `var outp =somefunction();` is replaced with `Utilities.sleep(30000);`, unfortunately, no error occurs with requesting by ajax. I apologize for this. So can you provide the detail flow and script for replicating your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike, ive included my code above, thanks

Comment: sorry for the getRange instead of the getRanges

Comment: no, I didn't misunderstand at all ... check the responses ... do they BOTH have CORS headers?

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw your additional script of `ambilberkas`, I cannot understand about the relationship between your 1st script and your additional script. Can you explain about it? By the way, if `ambilberkas` is the same with `somefunction`, when you manually run `ambilberkas` by giving the arguments, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @tanaike, yes, the somefunction is the same with ambilberkas above, if I manually run ambilberkas from code editor, it successfully run resulting id of the Google docs, and it's the same when I run the api url directly from new tab, it ran successfully, with same output. What frustrating me is when I fetch that url, it give CORS error

Comment: @jaromanda x, ok ill try checking the cors header in the responses

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood that `somefunction` is the same with `ambilberkas` and when `ambilberkas` is manually run by the script editor, no error occurs. In that case, can I ask you about the detail of your settings of Web Apps? And also, can you provide your script for requesting with ajax? By the way, when you redeployed the Web Apps as new version and test it again, what result will you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike, thank you for the fast respond,
i ran my web app on firebase hosting, above i add detail about the fetch on my web app,
and i already redeploy my gas and web apps with the error still there

Comment: the first request and second request to the api is actually pointing to the same API url, i just change the parameter, whereas the first call is calling some other function, and the second call is calling ambil berkas, here where its get weird, the first call is succeeded, ant the second is CORS error

Comment: Thank you for replying. I had thought that you use ajax for requesting. But I could understand that you are using fetch. I apologize for this. From your additional script, for example, how about testing to request to Web Apps using a simple fetch script like `fetch("URL of Web Apps").then((res) => res.json()).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))`? By the way, about the request to `ambilberkas`, how do you send the arguments?

Comment: @Tanaike, its still give CORS error, here i put the code in the codesandbox,in there you can see that first function working fine, and the ambilberkas is error :
https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-architecture-kzp27?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. At first, when you replaced `var outp =somefunction();` with `Utilities.sleep(30000);`, what result will you obtain? And, as the next step, in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the whole script of Google Apps Script side? Because from your current script, I cannot see about the script for the values giving to `ambilberkas` as the arguments. Because I think that if Google Apps Script occurs no error, `fetch` has no error.

Comment: thank you for responding @Tanaike, there on my last edit is all my code, in there you can see that cekstatus(the first call in my web app) is working fine, and ambilberkas is error

Comment: as the utilitites.sleep, its working fine, i add some function which you can check on the codesandbox above

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your latest replying, about your question of `so my conclusion is, when google app script execute some function that take long time(in my case 10s) it return CORS error when i fetch it, is it right? or im missing something?`, it was found that in your environment, when the worker of 30 seconds is run, no error occurs.

Comment: And about your additional script, although I'm not sure about your Spreadsheet, for example, when the script of `function test() {const e = {"parameter":{"tanggalujian":"16 Juni 2020","tanggal":"18 Desember 2020","prodi":"Pendidikan Agama Islam","nim":"T20161048","mode":"ambilberkas","waktu":"Selasa"}; ambilberkas(e.parameter.prodi,e.parameter.nim,e.parameter.tanggal,e.parameter.tanggalujian,e.parameter.waktu);}` is manually run at the script editor, what result will you obtain?

Comment: And also, can I ask you about the settings of your Web Apps? It's the values of `Execute the app as:` and `Who has access to the app:`.

Comment: @Tanaike, again, thankyou and sorry for the hassle, when i ran your test code from editor, it result as expected=11H2xAM9voF-q8vZld0gGvbdHwoeaB3DI, which is the google docs id, and to answer your other question, i run the code as mysefl, and anyone can access it, even anonymous, hence why the codesandbox above can run.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that it is required to confirm your whole script using your sample Spreadsheet. So can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you cannot do this, please don't worry. By the way, your script editor is new IDE?

Comment: [Edit] to quote the exact  text of the CORS error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ah,, so its a bug,, i debug my code and found out that this line is causing the error:

```
var op = DocumentApp.openById(documentId)
```

there is another thread discussing this:
[openbyid bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65357350/error-in-google-scripts-documentapp-openbyid)

and the current alternative solution is by using the v8 runtime.