# Error in google scripts - DocumentApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script

Since a couple of days im having this error:

**We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and
try again**

When this line its executed:

**var temp = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplate.getId());**

My code was working already, so i think its something internal of Google?

Any help? Thanks a lot

Alejandro

Comment: It may in fact be a Google error but there’s insufficient code there for us to reproduce the problem so we can’t really help you

Comment: As Cooper mentioned, how are we supposed to know what is the value of  `newTemplate.getId()` ? You don't need to give us the `id` itself, but you can show us the way you obtain it.

Comment: @Marios

This are the lines:

var template = DriveApp.getFileById(ID) 
var newTemplate = template.makeCopy(randname);
var temp = DocumentApp.openById(newTemplate.getId());

The previous 2 lines work just fine (i checked them), and as i say it was working just fine up to 16/12

Answer (score 1):

### It seems like there is curently a bug

See [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/175627112) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/175893282).

While you might get this error because of e.g. trying to open a non Google Docs document with DocumentApp, it is also possible that your problem is related to the bug.

give it a star to increase visibility.